Spring initializr- where is "Spring for Apache Geode"?
I am following "Accessing Data in Pivotal GemFire with REST" guide, I am trying to use the inializr. According to instructions, I should use "Spring for Apache Geode" dependency. I cannot find it, nor any dependency with "geode" string. What dependency should I use instead ? I saw "Spring support for Apache Geode (spring-data-geode)" post, but probably due to my lack of experience with Spring projects I have failed to utilize its information to use initializr with Apache Geode correctly.
 Update: After reading @D-Dᴙum comment, I followed his recommended approach. I found out that spring-data-geode cannot be found in Maven2. I did some reading in this blog post and tried to add version 1.0.0.APACHE-GEODE-INCUBATING-M3, but it was not inline with the code of this guide. Then I found the related github project, switched to version 2.7.18, the currently supported version for this project. Now the code seems to be compiling successfully. When I ran the application I got an error and found here that I need to update@SpringBootApplication to@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })

Th initialiser site won't necessarily give you the ability to add every dependency that you need, typically it would provision the most common libraries and spring starters. What you would do is bring in the spring-boot-starter dependency and say database dependencies and web dependencies. Once you have downloaded the project you'd need to add the more specialised dependencies such as 'Spring Apache Geode' manually. Or copy the dependency as given in the POM file in the referenced guide.
